# SSO with two Identity Servers

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I have two user groups. Internal users and External users. There are separate user stores and Separate IDPs(WSO2IS) for each user group. There are three web apps for internal users and two for External users. 
For the moment, Internal users only having access for the Internal apps and External users only having access to the external apps. 
Is there a way to provide SSO with external apps to the internal users, without clustering.

As a scenario;

- InUser is in the Internal User store, ExUser is in the External User store.
- InUser can access to InApp after authenticate from Internal_IS.
- ExUser can access to ExApp after authenticate from External_IS.
- Now need to provide SSO with ExApp to the InUser.But Ex_user couldn't have access to the InApp.

How can I achieve this with WSO2 IS 5.1.0?

Answer (score 0):

Clustering is something different and only needed for high availability. When you add providers, the users are already separated by their user store. You would need to add permissions to allow the users in each user store to access the same app. Check to see where your app permissions are defined.